# Unexpected event handling in webdriver/ selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is it possible for selenium to wait for an user input if an unexpected event occurs in the script(like a message box/ new window/ warning / alert or any other interruption)?
For example if some new functionality is added to the code and when selenium script is run, the test shouldn't break but should wait for manual intervention where the condition in the new functionality occurs.

Comment: Manual interruption is not allowed because you need to be able to handle multi-threaded scenarios.   If your test is run using "local WebDriver" rather than RemoteWebDriver then you can have your test do manual interruption only if its single threaded, IMHO.  How the interruption is implemented depends on the programming language you use and the implementation.  Obviously, if you run your tests using a Jenkins job server, you cannot have manual interaction there either.

Answer (score 1):

As we are automating the testing its meaningless if there requires user interruption, you have to handle all the unexpected events too.. I will try to give you one solution for that unexpected message box you can check whether the close button of that message box is visible or not and if it is visible then you can close that box..

Comment: Thanks Divi, yes I agree with you, but have heard from some selenium enthusiasts that selenium can handle any unexpected condition. On researching I found that AutoIT gives some help on this, but still requires that you know what windows might be expected. Could not find any other suggestions on the matter. Any help would be great. The expectation is that any new functionality added to the existing code(by developers) does not break our automation scripts.

Comment: I think now I understand what you want.If there is changes in the developer side then I think there is no better solution than to modify automation code for that page.

Comment: That would be the ideal scenario and would be handled in code maintenance. However the expectation is that if such a case occurs the existing selenium script does not break, but handles that (like to have a wait incorporated on any such occurrence, where in it would give an option of manual intervention). I know this is not a normal case for an automation but is there any way that selenium can handle this anomaly?

Comment: I don't think manual interruption is allowed in selenium.If you find any solution post your answer.